# Rails: can't migrate database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I'm trying migrate database with `bundle exec rake db:migrate` I get an error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your mysql server running?

Comment: run the mysql service

Comment: contents of database.yml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be different reasons. Either as vanda says your mysql server simply isn't running.

Or it placed the mysql.sock file in a different folder. In this case you can add the following line to config/database.yml:

```
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

(Obviously the path must be the right one, this may differ between installs and you may have to find the right path first)